# R - Extend a multi-dimensional array

Tags: r

I have a multidimensional array S:

```
> dim(S)
[1] 45 81  3 52
```

I would like to add one column in the third dimension to have:

```
> dim(S)
[1] 45 81  **4** 52
```

and preserve all the current data in S where they are.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is one potential base `R` solution with `[<-`.

```
S.new <- array(NA, dim=c(45, 81, 4, 52))
S.new[,,-4,] <- S                 # re-insert on all but the added extent
```

Basically, you just re-insert into your new array but by specifying the dimensions that exist in your old array.

---

We can test with a small toy example to see that it works::

```
arr <- array(rep(1:4, each=4), dim=c(2, 2, 2, 2))     # toy array
arr.new <- array(NA, dim=c(2, 2, 3, 2))               # increased dimension 3
```

And then one simple step does it:

```
arr.new[,,-3,] <- arr
```

Answer (score 6):

If you load in the `abind` package, you have access to

```
empty <- array(0, dim=c(45,81,52))
S <- abind(S,empty, along=3)
```