# (Nicely) Extend an array blockwise / along multiple dimensions

Tags: r, arrays, concatenation

Refering to this [SO-question on extending a multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662105/r-extend-a-multi-dimensional-array); I want to blockwise extend / concatenate two multidimensional arrays (i.e., along multiple dimensions?). Suppose the following

#### MWE

```
library(abind)

x <- matrix(1:12,3,4)
y <- x + 100

a0 <- 0 * x
abind(abind(x, a0), abind(a0, y), along = 1)

##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
## [1,]    1    4    7   10    0    0    0    0
## [2,]    2    5    8   11    0    0    0    0
## [3,]    3    6    9   12    0    0    0    0
## [4,]    0    0    0    0  101  104  107  110
## [5,]    0    0    0    0  102  105  108  111
## [6,]    0    0    0    0  103  106  109  112

x <- array(1:12, dim = c(2, 3, 2))
y <- x * 100

a0 <- 0 * x
abind(abind(x, a0), abind(a0, y), along = 1)
```

The `abind` and dummy array sequence is doing the trick. I do realize that I could acchieve the same result by initializing an empty array of target dimensions and subsequently filling it with the base arrays `x` and `y` (using a reasonably large index matrix; e.g. with the help from `expand.grid`).

#### My question

Is there a **nice**, that is **short**, way of doing that? Maybe I've missed some argument specifications mentioned in the `abind` manual. Is that even a reasonable request considering multidimensional arrays?

If not for arrays in general; what would the minimal way of doing that for two dimensional matrices be?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `direct.sum` function from the `matrixcalc v1.0-3` package.

```
direct.sum( x, y )
```

where x and y are matrices and the result is a block diagonal matrix.

See the documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/matrixcalc/versions/1.0-3/topics/direct.sum)

**Example:**

```
library(matrixcalc)
x <- matrix(1:12,3,4)
y <- x + 100
direct.sum(x,y)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    4    7   10    0    0    0    0
[2,]    2    5    8   11    0    0    0    0
[3,]    3    6    9   12    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0  101  104  107  110
[5,]    0    0    0    0  102  105  108  111
[6,]    0    0    0    0  103  106  109  112
```

Comment: thanks for this solution. Any chance you have an idea how to apply that approach to multidimensional arrays?

Comment: @Tom I could not find any reference on doing a direct sum on a multidimensional array. This doesn't mean there are none.